# Javascript set value of input field such that it registers

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, html-input

I'm trying to automate login to https://login.channeladvisor.com/ in Chrome.
Setting value of the username and password fields is easy:

```
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].setAttribute('value','username@gmail.com');
document.getElementsByName('password')[0].setAttribute('value','password123');
```

The fields update, but the website doesn't register the tntries until the text is input through keyboard (test it by pressing the 'Log In' button.

I've tried lots of stuff like these:

```
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].click();
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].focus();
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
document.getElementsByName('username')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown'));
```

And a lot more, but no luck

Comment: Two things: you don't have to use `.setAttribute()` to set the value; you can just use the `.value` property of the DOM node. The second thing is that browsers do not fire an event when you update the `.value`. You can trigger the event your self or simply call your event handler function directly.

Comment: If things are not working, it would be helpful if you could report any errors you're seeing in the console.

Comment: why clicking the element that you wrote your username for login, maybe there should be button or similar ?

Comment: @Pointy Yes I did that first, it didn't work for me either (had same result as setting the attribute)

Comment: @MetBr I was trying to somehow make the input field see there's an activity. I tried a lot of things. But yes, there's a login button there if you see the webpage, that accepts clicks.

Comment: those inputs may be designed to work with `input` event and with additional checking of `isTrusted` event flag, so you'll have a hard work to foolish them

Comment: @syduki is there a way to verify that's the case?

Comment: @erohtar sure, you should read the website source code :)